# Jest how to mock Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

I cant figure out how to mock firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword.

The function:

```
export const signIn = async (email:string, password:string) => {
    
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(async() => {
      const usersRef = collection(db, 'Users');
      ...
```

Firebase config:

```
const app = initializeApp(config);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import Login from './Login';
import auth from 'firebase/auth'

jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => {

  return {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(() => {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(null);
      });
    }),
    getAuth: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('Login', () => {

  it('Logs user in', async () => {
    render(<Login />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Log in/i));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

Error im getting:

```
(0, _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword)(_firebase.auth, email, password).then(async () => {
                                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried mocking firebase/app and firebase/firestore also but it hasnt helped.

Comment: Hey - I can't offer any help, but I am having almost exactly the same issue, and I also posted a question about it a couple of days ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748197/how-can-i-write-a-unit-test-to-check-that-a-react-component-method-calls-a-fireb. I've tried the same thing with other Firebase auth methods, and am hitting the same issue every time. I'll keep an eye here to see if you get any further with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for node tests.

```
jest.mock('firebase/auth');

describe('Login', () => {
  it('Logs user in', async () => {
    const mockedSignIn = jest.mocked(signInWithEmailAndPassword);
    mockedSignIn.mockResolvedValue(mockDeep<UserCredential>());

    const user = await getService().login('email', 'password');

    expect(mockedSignIn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(undefined, 'email', 'password');
    
  });
});
```