# How can I write a unit test to check that a React component method calls a Firebase auth method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm building a React web app with a Firebase backend. I'm cool with React and Firebase, and I'm able to implement all the functionality I need without issue.

However, I'm also using this project as an opportunity to learn unit testing, currently using React Testing Library and Jest.

I can successfully test for rendered UI elements. What I'm struggling to get my head around is how I can test for a successful call of the Firebase API, for example with the below form component which allows a user to request a password reset email.

So, as of now, I'm able to successfully test:

- if the form is rendered correctly
- if the correct UI (warning) elements are rendered when the form is submitted with an invalid or missing email address

What I also want to be able to test for is:

- if the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method is called when the form is submitted with a valid email address

I've stripped the component back to its most basic form (ignoring validation, etc, for now) to demonstrate. Users enter an email address, submit the form, and the Firebase method `sendPasswordResetEmail` is called.

My question is: how can I write a ***test*** that checks whether the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method is called successfully on form submit?

Is it even possible to test for this case?

Is this even the right question to ask? I'm super new to unit testing. :o)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../../lib/firebaseApp";
import { sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

const PasswordResetForm = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
      .then(() => {
        //Email sent
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="email" value={email || ""} onChange={handleChange} />
      <SubmitButton buttonText="Reset password" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default PasswordResetForm;
```

Here's a test I've written for one of the UI elements (for info only):

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

//Component
import PasswordResetForm from "../../../components/forms/passwordresetform";

describe("Password reset form", () => {
  it("Should render an email field", () => {
    render(<PasswordResetForm />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });
    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "email" });
    expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

I've also now attempted to write a test to check whether the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method is called successfully:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

//Component
import PasswordResetForm from "../../../components/forms/passwordresetform";


//Mock firebase
jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => {
  return {
    getAuth: () => jest.fn(),
    sendPasswordResetEmail: () => jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}),
  }
});



//UI tests
describe("Password reset form", () => {
  it("Should allow good email addresses and call sendPasswordResetEmail", async () => {
    render(<PasswordResetForm />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });
    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "email" });
    const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "submit" });
    const value = "user@domain.com";
    userEvent.type(input, value);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(sendPasswordResetEmail).toBeCalledWith(getAuth(), value);
  });
});
```

However, this is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail)(...).then is not a function

      42 |     if (dataValid) {
      43 |       sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
    > 44 |         .then(() => {
         |          ^
```

So, the question I now have is am I using `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({})` in the right way?

And if so, why isn't it working?